# Where do I import design components from vercel from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu using vercel's built-in packages

https://vercel.com/design/menu

However, in this documentation, it does not say how to import these things. I literally cannot figure out how to do this and I've spent like an hour doing it.

How do I import these packages?

Answer (score 1):

Vercel design system is not [open source](https://github.com/vercel/community/discussions/238) but [Geist UI](https://geist-ui.dev/) does a pretty job replicating most of the components.